# Input View Not Changing For UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have created two buttons. One called `Weight` and the other `Age`. Both of these buttons set the same UITextField as a first responder. However, if the `Weight` button is touched, the keyboard type becomes a number pad; if the `Age` button is touched, the keyboard type becomes a UIPickerVIew. Here is the code below:

```
@IBOutlet var weightButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var ageButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var userInput: UITextField!

let agePicker = UIPickerView()
let ageAsString =  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"]
var selectedAge: Double?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createAgePicker()
}

//ButtonsClicked
@IBAction func weightSearch(_ sender: Any) {
    wieghtResponse()
}

@IBAction func ageSearch(_ sender: Any) {
    ageResponse()
}

func userInputResponse() {
    userInput.inputView = nil
    if weightButton.isTouchInside {
        userInput.inputView = nil
        userInput.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
        userInput.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if ageButton.isTouchInside {
        userInput.inputView = nil
        userInput.inputView = agePicker
        userInput.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

//CreateAgePicker
func createAgePicker() {
    agePicker.delegate = self
    agePicker.backgroundColor = .white
    agePicker.tintColor = .clear
}
//Components
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
//Rows
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return ageAsString.count
}
//Labels
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return ageAsString[row]
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I click on the `Age` button, the picker view loads. However, when I click back on the `Weight` button, the input view doesn't revert back to a number pad and stays as the picker. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
func weightResponse(){
    userInput.inputView = nil // reset your input view for weight input
    userInput.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    userInput.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: perfect thank you. That solved it right away. I am having another problem however. When I click on any of the buttons, I have to cancel the search before I can click on another button. That is, say I click on the `Weight` button and the numeric pad loads, clinking on the `Age` button doesn't have an effect. Is there anyway I can fix that? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Off the top of my head, not totally sure. But you could try adding `userInput.resignFirstResponder()` at the start of each of your response functions?

Comment: I actually edited the user response functions and put them in a single function. I tried the `userInput.resignFirstResponder` and it is nor working. Any thing else I should try?

Comment: Nevermind, I added it to the individual button touch actions and it worked. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of some help!

Comment: would you mind looking at a new question that I posted?

Comment: `becomeFirstResponder()` should make it done ✅